# Jenkins Pipeline fails on checkout of Quarkus project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, quarkus

I'm trying to build a quarkus project with a jenkins pipeline. It fails with the following error

```
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'build/resources/main/META-INF/resources/index.html': Permission denied
error: unable to unlink old 'build/resources/main/application.properties': Permission denied
```

These files are part of the build folder in my project.
It builds successfully the first time a pipeline is created and run, but fails for all subsequent runs.
This is what my jenkinsfile looks like. I tried adding a step before a build to remove/rename the files, but no luck.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        APPLICATION_PATH = 'src/main'
        DOCKER_HOME      = "/docker/data/jenkins"
        WORKSPACE        = "workspace"
    }
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'openjdk:17-oracle'
                    args "-u root -v ${env.DOCKER_HOME}/${env.WORKSPACE}/${env.JOB_NAME}"
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                script {
                    sh './gradlew clean build'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? Have you reported the error with the incremental build upstream? And were you able to reproduce the error running the commands bare metal? Have you tried it? What was the error message when you tried to clean beforehand and what was the command? Please add all clarifications to the question by editing it.